# Waiting for several networking async calls in iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotificationcenter

From a view controller, as a result of a button action, I need to create a custom object that manages a set of asynchronous remote service calls, and call the method of such object that fires those service calls. I need the view controller to wait for all the async networking operations to have finished in order to update its view. Since the networking operations are async, I don't know how I'd communicate from the custom object managing this tasks to the view controller when all operations are done.

Here is the code I currently have. The code snippet in the view controller is like this (`result` var is not currently used):

```
- (void)loadData
{
   BOOL __block result = NO;

   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(dataLoadQueue, NULL);
   dispatch_async(queue,^{

      Loader *loader = [[Loader alloc] init];
      [loader loadData];

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (result) {
            // Update view and notify success
        }
        else {
            // Update view and notify error
        }
      });
   });

   dispatch_release(queue);
}
```

And this is the `loader` custom object side:

```
- (void)loadData
{
   if ([Reachability checkNetStatus]) {

      Service1 *service1 = [[Service1 alloc] init];
      [service1 callAsyncService];

      Service2 *service2 = [[Service2 alloc] init];
      [service2 callAsyncService];

      // More service calls
   }

   else {
      // Notify network not reachable
   }
}
```

Objects `service1, service2... serviceN` conform the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and I notify they have finished in its `connectionDidFinishLoading:` by means of the `NSNotificationCenter` (`loader` object is listening for such notifications). Then, I don´t know what is the correct way of making `loader` wait for all the networking operations, and notify back the view controller.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does loader always create the same set of Service objects? It looks like it from your posted code, since there's no arguments to Loader's loadData method.

Comment: @rdelmar yes, it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably lots of ways you could do this. First, I don't think there's any need to use GCD in the view controller -- loader is already doing things asynchronously, so the creation of loader is fast.

As for how Loader knows when all its network operations are done, you could just keep a list of strings in a mutable array, like "1 done", "2 done", etc. that would be the same as strings sent in the user info of the notifications called in connectionDidFinishLoading:. All the services could send the same notification, but with different user info. In the selector for the observer, remove the string identical to the one in the user info, and check if the array is empty -- when it is, all your services are done. At that point, I would use a delegate method to pass back the data to the view controller. Something like this in Loader:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.doneStrings = [@[@"1 done", @"2 done", @"3 done", @"4 done"] mutableCopy];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationReceived:) name:@"SeriveFinishedNotification" object:nil];
}

-(void)notificationReceived:(NSNotification *) aNote {
    [self.doneStrings removeObjectIdenticalTo:[aNote.userInfo objectForKey:@"doneString"]];
    if (self.doneStrings.count == 0)
        [delegate doSomethingWithTheData: theData];
}
```

You would probably need to some other things like handle the case where some of the network operations fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait until the async tasks were done, you can use a semaphore. See the example below, the logic is pretty simply. I think you can easily adapt to your case.

```
//create the semaphore
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

[objectManager.HTTPClient deletePath:[address addressURL] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

      //some code here executed in background

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); //sends a notification to release the semaphore

    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

       //some other code here also executed in background

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); //sends a notification to release the semaphore
    }];


//holds the thread until the dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore) is send
while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW))
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the details of how these asynchronous requests work, but another approach is to make these asynchronous requests `NSOperation` objects that you submit to a `NSOperationQueue`. (AFNetworking is an example of this sort of implementation.) When you do that, you can create yet another `NSOperation` to be triggered upon the completion of the  network request operations, by make it dependent upon those network request operations. Thus it will only run when all of the network requests are done. Using an `NSOperation`-based solution enjoys other benefits, too (e.g. you can use `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount` to let you enjoy concurrency, but not run too many concurrent requests at any given time).

#### References

- Ray Wenderlich's [How To Use NSOperations and NSOperationQueues](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)
- [Defining a Custom Operation Object](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW16) in Apple's *Concurrency Programming Guide*

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit more familiar with the approach I've selected than with `NSOperation`, but if using `NSOperationQueue` can offer benefits on scenarios like this, I'll take the time to follow your references

Comment: @AppsDev While subclassing operations is a very useful technology to familiarize yourself with at some point, if you don't want to get buried in the subtle issues involved, you can also look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), a well-regarded third party networking library that (a) does this for you; and (b) generally makes network programming much easier than doing it yourself.

Comment: In answer to the question of benefits, one of the key advantages is the one I alluded to in my answer, namely the ability to employ a queue with, say, with 5 concurrent operations, so you can queue up a bunch of requests and the operation queue takes care of not only the concurrency, but scheduling of them so you don't have too many running at any given time. It also provides nice mechanism for canceling operations. Very useful when retrieving a tone of images in, say, a tableview. Or [doing a lot of downloads](https://github.com/robertmryan/download-operation).